# Fix stubborn 'Setting locale failed.'

Tags: ubuntu, localization

I have a very stubborn, well-known locale error on Ubuntu 9.10:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "custom.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Tried the following:

- Added `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` to /etc/environment
- Run `apt-get install --reinstall locales` (error: perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). /usr/bin/mandb: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct)
- Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. Result: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory, and then updates locales all locales including en_US.UTF-8
- `sudo locale-gen` updates all locales successfully, including en_US.UTF-8
- `sudo locale-gen un_US en_US.UTF-8` gives no error nor other output
- In `/etc/default/locale` it says `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`
- `echo $LANG` gives en_US.UTF-8
- `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` says en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
- `locale -a` gives me:

```
C
en_AG
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_NG
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

So well... I am pretty much out of options I can think of. Anybody any idea??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem and found the solution. You have to recreate the `custom.UTF-8` locale def (the "custom" file is probably there because you changed the date or time format). Run

```
sudo localedef -f UTF-8 -i custom custom.UTF-8
```

Another way to do this is to add the locale to the ones you want `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to configure for you. On Debian:

```
echo 'custom.UTF-8 UTF-8' |sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

On Ubuntu:

```
echo 'custom.UTF-8 UTF-8' |sudo tee -a /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

You could also try to install the `locales-all` package, to avoid having to generate any locales ever again.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only thing that worked for me and it's super easy.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem on a Ubuntu 10.04 server this way:

```
root@hostname:~# export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
root@hostname:~# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
root@hostname:~# export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
root@hostname:~# locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
root@hostname:~# dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem on a Ubuntu 10.04 server this way:

```
$ export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

To make the changes permanent you need to add there variable into `/etc/environment`

```
$ sudo vi /etc/environment
```

Comment: It would be better to set the locale variables (`LANGUAGE`, `LANG`, & `LC_ALL`) in you local profile or shell .rc file -- while in *your* environment everyone might be in the same location, speaking the same language, etc. sometimes you have to coexist on a server with people from all over the world.  That's why you can set things like this with environment variables :-)

Answer (score 0):

> LC_TIME = "custom.UTF-8"

This one looks quite odd, it should be `"en_US.UTF-8"`, not `"custom.UTF-8"`
You should grep `/etc` to see where it comes from.